# Mathematica 12.1 dialog after closing "vibrates"

Tags: front-end, version-12.1

I have installed Mathematica 12.1 on my Linux - Manjaro KDE  20.0, KDE Plasma version 5.18.4, KDE frameworks version 5.69.0, QT version 5.14.2.

The dialog box which appears after I close any notebook appears to "vibrate" up and down. It becomes difficult to click the close/quit button. I cannot figure out why does this happen and how do I stop it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for Wolfram Support than for this forum.

Comment: I do not understand what was the problem but I had to install my whole operating system (Manjaro 20.0.1, 5.6.12, Plasma 5.18.5) for some other reason and subsequently install Mathematica again. That somehow cleared the problem.